# How to wrap tabs into rows

Tags: flutter, row

i'm new to flutter , i'm trying to wrap the tabs to fit in different rows but it's not working, keep you please tell me what should should i add to my code... i appreciate the help.....................................................................thanks

```
Column(
           children:[Card(
      child: Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.green,Colors.white,Colors.red],),),
        child: Text(
          "journals ",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color: Colors.black),
        ),
      ),
    ), SingleChildScrollView(
      child:Row(

  children: _list.map((dynamic link) => _urlButton(context,link)).toList(),
                                    ),),]}
Widget _urlButton(BuildContext context, dynamic url) {
return Container(child:
   Card(child:Row(children: [Tab(
                  child: IconButton(
                    iconSize: 100,
                    icon: Image.asset(url["a"]),
      onPressed: () => _handleURLButtonPress(context, url),
    )),],),
                 ),);
 }
void _handleURLButtonPress(BuildContext context, dynamic url) {
Navigator.push<dynamic>(context,
    MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(builder: (context) => WebViewContainer(url["b"])));
```

}

Comment: please attach an image/screenshot of what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do here, as there is possibly a completely different way to approach the problem that would be a lot more simple. Are you trying to add tab rows to a bottom navigation bar? Oftentimes, something custom like that is easier done by "faking it", meaning you make a widget that looks like what you think it is, but it's really something else. This is how you get a gradient in the AppBar. You can't put a gradient in the AppBar, but you can omit the AppBar, use a Column and make the first child a Container that looks like an AppBar

Comment: i want to put three buttons (tab) in each row, i think it should be done using the Wrap widget but i'm not sure